# Erlang alternative to trap_exit?

Tags: process, erlang, exit, erlang-supervisor, gen-server

I would like to execute some code when my gen_server is stopped. I have my gen_server trapping exits (I added `process_flag(trap_exit, true)` to the init callback). This works well as `terminate/2` is always called before the process exits. I know that since I am trapping exits linked processes that crash do not crash the gen_server I created. I could work around this but I am wondering if there is an alternative to using `process_flag(trap_exit, true)` to achieve this?

I just want a "before the process exits" callback. Does something else like this exit?

Comment: You want linked processes to kill the `gen_server`, but you also want `terminate` (or similar) to be called when it exits?

Comment: Exactly. It's my understanding that if I am trapping exits no other process can cause my gen_server to crash, which it really should if something goes wrong.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that trapping exits just causes it to run terminate and then exit. Does it actually prevent the gen_server from stopping?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Pascal's answer is perfectly right, but I would like to propose another aproach.

Sometimes you want to spawn processes by the `gen_server`, but usually, you can put them in the supervision hierarchy, which is much safer. You can have those processes and `gen_server` spawned by the same supervisor with `one_for_all` *restart strategy*. If one of the processes dies, they all get restarted. Secondly you have to specify timeout for *shutdown strategy* - this will ensure, that the terminate function will be called.

Comment: This makes sense... So in this case would it be ok to use trap_exit as the gen_server would not be linked to anything?

Comment: In this case, you can forget `trap_exit`. It is ok not to use it. It usually is better not to use it, when you can use supervisors.

Answer (score 4):

Fron doc:

> When trap_exit is set to true, exit signals arriving to a process are
>   converted to {'EXIT', From, Reason} messages, which can be received as
>   ordinary messages. If trap_exit is set to false, the process exits if
>   it receives an exit signal other than normal and the exit signal is
>   propagated to its linked processes. Application processes should
>   normally not trap exits.

This means that the process which has is trap_exit flag set to true will not exit if any of its linked processes die abnormally. It must have a receive block with a clause to catch any message of the form  `{'EXIT', From, Reason}`.  In this receive clause you can do what you need before eventually stopping your process.

in a gen_server you will have to write a callback `Module:handle_info({'EXIT', From, Reason}, State) -> Result`.